# HOW TO FIX: Service Unavailable in IIS 6 windows XP?

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-xp, iis-6, windows-2003-webserver

I'm trying to fix the issue Service Unavailable in IIS 6 with Windows XP x64

The defaults applications are not working too and my application neather.

So when i browse my application, the message displaed in the browser is "Service Unavailable"

I already restart the iis service
I already add a new application pool
It seems Network Service is added by default.

It is a .NET application framework v1.1
I'm trying to make it run locally in a VM Virtualbox

What can i do to fix this? thanks

[image]

Comment: ....you know support for Windows XP ended a long time ago, right?

Comment: @mason yes man, i am not asking for microsoft support. But i would like  to know how to fix that issue. Some companies still are migrating some old applications. Do you have any ide to fix that? any idea?  regards!

Comment: Did you look in the event viewer to see if there's any related error messages?

Comment: @mason thank you... that event viewer helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i could find the error by myself following these steps:

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?348106-RESOLVED-HTTP-1-1-503-Service-Unavailable

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/894435/how-to-switch-between-the-32-bit-versions-of-asp-net-1-1-and-the-64-bi

ASP.NET 1.1, 32-bit version
To run the 32-bit version of ASP.NET 1.1, follow these steps:
1.  Click Start, click Run, type cmd, and then click OK.

2. Type the following command to enable the 32-bit mode:
   cscript %SYSTEMDRIVE%\inetpub\adminscripts\adsutil.vbs SET W3SVC/AppPools/Enable32bitAppOnWin64 1
3. Type the following command to install the version of ASP.NET 1.1 and to install the script maps at the IIS root and under:
   %SYSTEMROOT%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322\aspnet_regiis.exe -i
4. Make sure that the status of ASP.NET version 1.1.4322 is set to Allowed in the Web service extension list in Internet Information Services Manager.

For beginners.. %SYSTEMROOT% is the Windows directory... in my case C:WINDOWS

Now this initially did nothing for me... so i navigated to the link in windows explorer, found adsutil.vbs and double clicked. It then asked me if i wanted to enable cscript (or something like that - can't remember cos i clicked too fast). Once i double clicked a second time all went well.

My Visual Studio was working again